# I am unable to get the dompdf lib to work in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, dompdf, wordpress-rest-api

Hi i am developing a wordpress plugin that will generate pdf from html document and am trying to implement the dompdf for this purpose. But i keep getting error:

Uncaught Error: Class 'Dompdf' not found in

Below is my code:

```
function generate_certificate()
{

// include autoloader
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
 $dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');


// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();

}
```

Comment: //$dompdf = new Dompdf(); 
why this line commented ?

Comment: sorry about that i did that when i was trying to debug the issue. Even after uncommenting that it still does not work. Any help.